# Is there a way to cut only the first gap from histogram and take all the remain values in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, histogram

I have a data frame with fields: **'unique years', 'counts'**. I plotted this data frame and i am getting the following histogram: [histogram - example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrlRy.png). I need to define a **start year** variable but if i have empty gaps at the starting point of histogram i need to skip them and shift the **starting year**. I was wondering if there is a **pythonic** way to do this. In the histogram - example plot, i have a not empty bin at the starting point but then i have a big gap with empty bins. So i need to find the point with a continuous not empty bins and define this point as a starting year (for the above sample i need the starting year as 1935). The **n** numpy.ndarray is giving me information about empty or not bins but i need a efficient way to resolve this. Thank you :)

**Sample of my data frame:**

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'unique_years': [1907, 1935, 1938, 1939, 1940],
        'counts'      : [11, 14, 438, 85, 8]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['unique_years', 'counts'])
```

**code for the histogram plot**

```
   (n, bins, patches) = plt.hist(df.unique_years, bins=25, label='hst')
   plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your question is that 'continuous' is not really well defined here. Do you mean that every *year* should have a non-empty count (that is fairly easy to do as you can filter your data for that prior to building your histogram), or should every consecutive *bucket* be non empty? If the latter, this means that you must:

1. Build your histogram
2. Filter your data on the resulting bins
3. Either use the filtered histogram or re-bin the remaining data, with bins sizes not guaranteed to stay the same  (so it is possible that you have the same issue with the new bins!)

As it is difficult to know exactly what is relevant in your exact case, I think the best answer would be to give you a set of tools that you can use as you see fit for the exact problem that you are encountering:

1. I want to filter my data starting from a certain date

```py
filtered = df.unique_years[df.unique_years > 1930]
```

2. I want to find the second non-empty bin

```py
(n, x) = np.histogram(df.unique_years, bins=25)
second_nonempty = np.where(n > 0)[0][1]
```

From there you can:

- rebin your filtered data:

```
(n, x) = np.histogram(df.unique_years, bins=25)
second_nonempty = np.where(n > 0)[0][1]
# Re-binning on the filtered data
plt.hist(df.unique_years[df.unique_years >= n[second_nonempty]], bins=25)
```

- Plot your histogram directly on the filtered bins:

```
(n, x) = np.histogram(df.unique_years, bins=25)
second_nonempty = np.where(n > 0)[0][1]
# Forcing the bins to take the provided values
plt.hist(df.unique_years, bins=x[second_nonempty:])
```

Now the 'second_nonempty' above can of course be replaced by any estimator of where you want to start, e.g.:

```
# Last empty bin + 1
all_bins_full_after = np.where(n == 0)[0][-1] + 1
```

Or anything else really

Comment: Thank you Val. Your second approach resolve my issue. I didn't want to just filter my data based on years but to find exactly the empty bins and re-bin.

Answer (score 0):

This should work to eliminate all the bins that are not consecutive. I am working mainly on the df. You can use this to plot your histogram

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['unique_years', 'counts'])
yd = df.unique_years.diff().eq(1)
df[yd|yd.shift(-1)]
```

this is the result you would get:

[image]

Comment: if i have this one: data = {'unique_years': [1907, 1935, 1938, 1939, 1940, 1944],
                                         'counts'          : [11, 14, 438, 85, 8, 102]}                                     again i am missing the range (1940-1944). I only want to skip the range (1907-1934) and start from 1935.

Comment: Yes you will because the idea is to remove years that are not consecutive. Like Val suggested, it depends from the idea of continuous you have.

Comment: Filtered your data  df[df.unique_years > 1930] or a simple plt.xlim() would do the job.